# Ubuntu server: after upgrading to 22.04 LTS my disk space decreased from 54% to 30%. How can I free up some space?

Tags: ubuntu, disk-space-utilization, ubuntu-22.04

I recently upgraded an old VM from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04 and 22.04.
Before the update, I had ~50GB of free space, now I have 24GB.
I already run `apt autoremove`, I purged unused kernel files and emptied apt cache.
I also completely removed mySql, and deleted all the DB files, since they weren't in use anymore, but I just gained few GBs.
Is there something more that I can do to free up some disk space? Maybe some other cache or temporary files that might have been left on disk?
I connect to the VM via SSH, so I cannot use any "visual" software to understand were the large files are, and what they are.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Look for what is taking up space. The `tree` command is your friend.

Comment: Thanks! I found out that there are 26GB+ of space taken by /var/lib/fail2ban I need to understand if it is safe to remove those files or not.

Answer (score 0):

I used `ncdu` to browse the directory tree. I was able to find out that the fail2ban folder in `/var/lib/fail2ban` contained more than 30GB of old databases. Removing them, everything is now back to normal.